# alert() disables load() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to understand how the jQuery load() works.

So I wrote an empty `<body>` in index.html and an external.html (containing a colored, `<div>`), and included google's 1.7.2 jquery.min.js.

If I write

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").load("external.html");
});
```

The colored `<div>` shows up correctly. However, if I add an alert to the script,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").load("external.html");
    alert("Loaded");
});
```

the alert will show but the div will not be there.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Click the "Ok" button and the load will be allowed to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the comple callback of load (since `load` is async) to ensure the load operation is completed.

```
$("body").load("external.html", function(){
   alert("Loaded"); //<-- This ensures load operation is complete whether success of failure
});
```

With your code it will just kickoff the load and then execute the alert (which will block the ui) and once it is dismissed you will see the contents getting loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").load("external.html"); //<-- Starts the async operation
    alert("Loaded"); //<-- Just alerts and blocks the ui and once this is done and load operation is complete you will see the new contents getting loaded.
});
```

You see that alert disable the load because `alert` blocks the ui thread till it is dismissed and no script can run at the same time. So the load operation will be completed (provided how long it takes for the ajax call to get the content to be loaded) only after you have dismissed the alert.

Comment: I see. Let me see if I understand the process: since the load() takes time to load, therefore the browser choose to move forward when load() is running. As it finishes the last line (alert), the browser just ignore what is still running and shut the process down?

Comment: @Lelouch That is the way asynchronous operation works... All the sequential scripts will run before the load (or any asyc calls) is completed. You see it especially since you are using an alert which blocks the ui thread.

Comment: Strange. A few minutes ago I used Safari 7 to test, and the div does not show up even after the alert is dismissed. And now 10 minutes later it correctly shows div after the alert. Thanks!

Comment: @Lelouch Might have been issue with the ajax call, it might have failed during that time. You can check the network console for the status...

Answer (score 0):

Since, you want to show an alert box after you have loaded your `external.html`, you should use a callback for `$.load` function, which is fired when the event has finished, like this:

```
$("body").load("external.html", function(){
   alert("Loaded");
});
```

The above will ensure that the alert is shown only when the `external.html` has been loaded. While your current code shows the alert as soon as the `load` statement is started and this in turn cancels the effects of the `load`.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/